# Is there punishment for people who badly/viciously edit community wikis?

Tags: discussion, edits, community-wiki

Just as the title says, from my observation I think there's (currently) no penalty for a bad edit to a CW, not even malicious edits. Anyone with 100 rep (or an assoc bonus) can do this.

So questions:

1. Any mechanics to prevent/stop unfriendly edits?
2. Any punishment/penalty to unfriendly editors?

Comment: Report the behavior to a moderator

Comment: Custom flag, include offending revision # in your flag message. Rollback, once at most, don't get in a rollback war, a mod will handle it. Don't engage in comments.

Comment: @iBug Oh good. :) The existing comments/answers are sufficient as a response, then. If ever there is actual abuse of CW, we can revisit and figure out what (if anything) can be done. But in the meantime, this is a reasonable support question to describe the current process. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 8):

If you ever see an example of a bad edit to a Community Wiki post, then if you are able you should either roll it back or edit it to a state which is at least as useful as the post was before it was badly edited.

If you ever see an example of a malicious edit to a Community Wiki post, then I think you should flag it.

I think it is always best to focus on improving posts rather than punishing people.